# Create variable from unassigned text

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, text, line

I'm trying to set up a program to be able to read in text located the the program file but which is not assigned to a variable.

What I mean by that is:

```
      There once was a boy who went on an adventure.
      He did many, many thing. Yada, yada, yada.

      [begin code here to read text]
```

I'm trying to design it to take in the typed lines of text and then be able to give variable names to each line until it reaches a stopping point like a blank like or a line with only a period. Assuming the text will begin on line 2.

If anybody has any ideas on how to make this work they would be very much appreciated.

Comment: That won't work, because if your file has random text in it like that, it won't be valid Python syntax and your code won't run.  You can't have code in a file with undelimited data and have that same code parse that same file.  You'll have to think of something else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you tried smuggling the text in as a docstring?

```
"""Test Doc String"""

print __doc__
```

Results in (if this code is saved in source.py):

```
 me@Bob:~$ python source.py
 Test Doc String
```

This relies upon keeping your program within a single file. If you import that file (e.g. from source.py to target.py) you would then have to refer to that docstring using the name of the source file (e.g. source.**doc**). Anyway, you can assign **doc** to the variable of your choice and then parse away...

But do you really want to do this? Why not read the text in from a separate text file?